# Parentheses and Unary Operator Precedence in Java

Tags: java, operators, expression, unary-operator

As per the order of precedence of operators, `()` is evaluated before unary operators like `++` or `--`. But let us consider the following code:-

```java
int x = 1;
x = 2 + (x++);
```

If `x++` is executed first, the value of `x` should have been updated to 2, and hence the value of x should have been `4`. However, on executing the code, the value of `x` is `3`. Does this mean that the expression was evaluated without considering the `()` around `x++`, or am I missing something?

Comment: x++ is post increment operation. The value of x++ expression is x. Then x is incremented. So, your code becomes x = 2 + 1 = 3.

Comment: From [the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2): “The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable *before* the new value is stored.” (emphasis is from the spec, not added by me)

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to explain this.

If you enclose the (x++). It is still evaluated, but its value is used before the increment (++) operation.

The order of your code goes like this:

1. (x++) is evaluated first. At this point x is still 1 and (x++) returns the original value of x **(1)** AND THEN increments x to 2.
2. After the x++ in parentheses is evaluated, the expression becomes x = 2 + 1, as the:

   *Post-increment operator x++ returns the current value of x and then increments x.*
   *Therefore, in the expression *x++** returns the current value of x, **(which is 1)** and then increments x to 2.

   So at the end of this step the expression x = 2 + 1 is 3.
3. At the end the result of the addition (3) is assigned to x. So the x is now 3.

**For your code to return 4, you should use "++x" (pre-increment operator)
This operator increments x first then returns the updated value of x. if you use the ++x in an expression, x is incremented before its value is used.**

Hopefully I explained it well. :D

Answer (score 1):

> *"... As per the order of precedence of operators, `()` is evaluated before unary operators like `++` or `--`. ..."*

The expression will be evaluated from *left* to *right*.
*[The Java® Language Specification – Chapter 15. Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)*

> *"... Does this mean that the expression was evaluated without considering the `()` around `x++`, or am I missing something?"*

The parentheses are not denoting when the *unary operator* is evaluated.

I suggest reviewing the following *Java* tutorial.
*[Operators (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)*